# String from string-array use in a .Java

Tags: android, arrays, string, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to use a Option Menu for the user use switch the Map Type.
hear code like i already use.

strings.xml

```css
    <string-array name="map_name">
        <item>Normal</item>
        <item>Hybrid</item>
        <item>Satellite</item>
        <item>Straßenkarte</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="map_string">
        <item>"MAP_TYPE_NORMAL"</item>
        <item>"MAP_TYPE_HYBRID"</item>
        <item>"MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE"</item>
        <item>"MAP_TYPE_ROADMAP "</item>
       </string-array>
```

Einstellungen.java

```js
public class Einstellungen extends PreferenceActivity
        implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        Preference map_string = findPreference(getString(R.array.map_string));
        map_string.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And now here i need some hind:

MapsActivity.java

```js
                        public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
                            String mst = getResources().getString(R.array.map_string);
                            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.mst);
```

I think i have a big think error in my head.
Can someone please give me a hind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, won't

```
String mst = getResources().getString(R.array.map_string);
```

cause problems.  Your trying to getString() on a string-array and pass it to a string.

Comment: Yes, but i only want the user choise from the array.

Comment: Maybe have a string in your Einstenllungen class that that is initialized to the users choice, and OnPreferenceChangeListener changes the value of that string.  This could be done through a [singleton class](https://gist.github.com/Akayh/5566992).  You can then reference that string in onMapReady call.  I am not sure if this is a solution you are looking for.